# Flyout does not show or is blank Facebook Like button

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

The flyout that allow people to comments on URLs after they like those URLs have been working fine on all of my websites until 2 or 3 weeks ago.

It looks like this is Facebook bugs after some changes they made (secretly as always).
It has been reported [here](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/292382624119910).

A lot of people have made the same complaints as mine.
While waiting for Facebook to work on this (I can only hope that they will do asap), can anyone shed some light on this please?

Please don't mention `overflow: hidden` as a cause because my Facebook Send button' flyout is working perfectly fine, unless you are absolutely sure about a solution for this problem.

It looks like the `div` for the flyout briefly appeared after I clicked "Like" but then quickly disppeared
[image: trace of the flyout]

Comment: While I don't mind receiving "Tumbleweed" bagde, no one really bothers or knows anything about this issue at all, seriously?

Comment: Don't you ever wonder why all out of a sudden, the flyout stopped showing up on mashable.com, techcrunch.com and cnn.com? I really turned to stackoverflow.com for a serious place to receive serious answers for my serious questions :(

Comment: I can't see a lot of activities on the following bug report either (this has nothing to do with you guys though, just saying) https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/292382624119910

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seemed to have to do with my Facebook account.

I have 2 Facebook accounts and testing shows that everything worked fine for my other Facebook account.

This could be due to some temporary issues on Facebook end or they deliberately blocked this functionality for my Facebook accounts because of suspected spamming activity.

The issue resolved itself after a while.

Answer (score 0):

This Facebook bug report got some acknowledgement: http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/293075054049400

Basically, one gets this behavior if secure browsing is enabled on the Facebook user's account.

Comment: I'm getting this behavior and do not have secure browsing enabled on my account...